# How do I extract numbers from a comma-separated sequence using a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string-formatting, number-formatting

I have the following string as an example:

```
var str = "3,000, 2000, 1,000"
```

and I want to extract `3000, 2000, 1000` using regex `str.match(/\d+/g)` but the result is wrong:

```
['3', '000', '2000', '1', '000']
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Well, you don't take into account the `,` as a thousands separator ...

Comment: The input is malformed. If you are using `,` as the separator for each number, then you cannot use it within the number. `['3', '000', '2000', '1', '000']` is indeed the right answer when given `"3,000, 2000, 1,000"` as input.

Comment: @Fractalism but you could argue that the separator is not just a comma here, but comma followed by a space. And with that you _have_ a format here that can be processed without ambiguity.

Comment: @Fractalism sure you can. But you have to handle it correctly ... A `,` within two numerical characters is a thousands separator. a `,` followed by a space is a list separator

Comment: @CBroe I see, you have a point there.

Comment: Please undo your edit,  `"3,000, 2000, 1,000"` and `"3,000, 2000 and 1,000"` are a totally different questions, and will make the current comments & answers confusing.  With such a change it would make more sense to ask another questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Answer:

```
const str = "3,000, 2000, 1,000"
const patt = /(\d+(\,)?)+\d*/g;
const res = (str.match(patt)).map(ele=> +ele.replace(/\,/g, ""))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Either use the return value of `map` or switch to a `forEach`

Comment: This wil fail with numbers with multiple thousand seperators. For example 1,300,000.

Comment: a `push` in the callback of a `map` is sort of an antipattern ...

Comment: Thank you for your support. Are there any drawbacks to my code?

Comment: Your code will fail to recognize numbers from 1..9 (ie only one digit) You should replace `(\d+(\,)?)+` with `(\d+(\,)?)*`

Comment: Thank you for your supporting. I didn't think too many things, What a shame. :).

Comment: Ok I think this is the correct answer. Also works with this string: `3,000, 2000 and 1,000`

Answer (score 3):

No need for regex. Just split by `" "`, remove all the `,` from the result and parse it to a number.

```js
var str = "3,000, 2000, 1,000";
var nums = str.split(" ").map(x => +x.replaceAll(",", ""))
console.log(nums)
```

Comment: It is also good method to solve problem easily.